# SSH and Quotes in Informix SQL

Tags: sql, ssh, informix

I have following line of code in the stored procedure where I need to add SSH to call remotely.

```
LET Cmd = 'cd /tmp; 
echo "==== Starting' || USER || ' @ ' || TIMESTAMP || ' ====" >> ' || LOGFILE || ';'
```

I changed this to:

```
LET cmd=  "ssh user@host 'cd /tmp; 
echo "==== Starting' || USER || ' @ ' || TIMESTAMP || ' ====" >> ' || LOGFILE || ';'";
```

The problem with this is after `ssh user@host 'cd /tmp; echo` it expects `;` but it finds `===` and throws Near pointer error (syntax error). Anyone has any idea on how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

In Informix you can start a string with " or ', in the first statement the string is started with ' and you could use " freely inside the string but in the second statement you start the string with ", if you wish to use the " inside the string you must escape it with a backslash.

You can try with this:

```
LET cmd=  "ssh user@host 'cd /tmp; 
echo \"==== Starting" || USER || " @ " || TIMESTAMP || " ====\" >> " || LOGFILE || ";'"
```